# Issue using search_api_ranges with search_api_ajax

Tags: search

I have set up search_api_solr - integrating search_api_ajax, facetapi and search_api_ranges into the results for a better flow.

I keep hitting an issue with regards to search_api_ranges where initially, for example; when a search runs on a taxonomy view which returns indexed nodes with the tag 'toyota', the link is always originally structured as:

```
mysite.com/car-tags/toyota/field_car_price/%5B1000%20TO%202000%5D
```

When clicking this, a 404 page not found is returned.

However! If I run the search again, this time clicking around the other facets - seeing the ajax working nicely, it's as if something triggers the ranges api, and each link is now:

```
 mysite.com/search_api_ajax/taxonomy/term/2/field_car_price/%5B1000%20TO%202000%5D
```

When clicking this, the ajax works fine.

Anyone come across this before?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to `Search Api ranges` module. There is already a patch for similar problem.

Kindly check patch at https://drupal.org/node/1987232 or use the updated module. I hope it will help for you.

Comment: If pending edit will get approved, it will be not so bad. But few words of explanation why this patch and what it changes might help, too. Update: edit was apparently approved second after my comment :D